# Using XSLT to fold together different types of elements

Tags: xml, xslt

Say I have the following:

```
<document>

    <foods>
        <food id = "1" name="apple"></food>
    </foods>

    <shopping-list>
        <item food-id="1" qty="10"></item> 
    </shopping-list>

</document>
```

How can I use XSLT to create a list of elements that combine the data from items and their referenced foods.

ex:

```
<food-item-list>
    <food-item name="apple" qty="10">
    </food-item>
</food-item-list>
```

Is this possible in XSLT? Or is there a different technology that can be employed?  The goal is to not have to write a program to do this.

Comment: is `food-id` IDREF to `id` of food element?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The efficient approach to this kind of cross referencing in XSLT is to define a *key*

```
<xsl:key name="foodById" match="food" use="@id" />
```

You can then use the `key` function to look up the `food` element(s) given a particular `id` value.

```
<xsl:template match="item">
  <food-item qty="{@qty}" name="{key('foodById', @food-id)/@name}" />
</xsl:template>
```

Or if you don't want to hard-code the attribute names and simply want *all* attributes of both elements (except the cross-reference itself) then

```
<xsl:template match="item">
  <food-item>
    <xsl:copy-of select="@*[local-name() != 'food-id']" />
    <xsl:copy-of select="key('foodById', @food-id)/@*[local-name() != 'id']" />
  </food-item>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I was trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

If your question is just *Is this possible in XSLT?*  Yes, it is very much possible and easy assuming `food-id` is `IDREF` to `id` of `<food>`

Comment: I'm sure the question is *not* just "is this possible"... I'm pretty sure anybody asking would also like to know how, even if they don't literally state it

Comment: Haha, programmers are so literal :)  Can anyone share a solution to this?

Comment: @freefaller you're right but I'd expect OP to show what s/he tried before spoon feeding a solution

Comment: In which case, point it out with a comment rather than a flippant answer

Answer (score 0):

Try this for size:

```
<xsl:for-each select="food">
  <xsl:element name="food-item">
    <xsl:attribute name="name">
      <xsl:value-of select="@name" />
    </xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:attribute name="qty">
      <xsl:value-of select="//shopping-list/item[@food-id=current()/@id]/@qty"/>
    </xsl:attribute>
  </xsl:element>
</xsl:for-each>
```